# How can I set an auto numeric name generator for image uploads, using a singleton pattern counter

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-upload, singleton

So my Problem is that I have to create a Singleton pattern counter for numeric name giving. For example "1", "2", "3" etc. The idea is that every time i start the application and the Server(tomcat), it gets the last number and when I upload another image it should continue from there. Lets say the last one was "43", so the the next time I start the application it should know it and put "44" for the next image upload.

I'm not that good in Java so please give me some patience :)

This is my FileUploadServlet. It handles the request from the fileUploadForm.jsp by taking the file from the submit.

```
package upload;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import utils.FormatChecker;
import utils.UnzipFile;

//Servlet for handling the Upload request from the Index.jsp
@MultipartConfig
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

// Instace of the FileUpload object
private FileUploader uploader = new FileUploader();

    // Instance of the FormatChecker object
private FormatChecker checker = new FormatChecker();

    // Instance of the UnzipFile object
private UnzipFile unzip = new UnzipFile();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String SAVE_FOLDER = "C:\\Users\\cuche\\Desktop\\tomcat\\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\\webapps\\files";

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String contentType;
    boolean isFormatValid;

    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    contentType = filePart.getContentType();
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    String appPath = context.getRealPath("/");
    String fileNameOld = getFileName(filePart);
    String fileNameNew = appPath + fileNameOld;

    isFormatValid = checker.check(contentType);
```

pleas ignore the part with the FileUnziper

```
    if (isFormatValid == true) {

        if (contentType == ("application/x-zip-compressed")) {

            unzip.FileUnziper(fileNameNew, SAVE_FOLDER);

        } else {
            //gets the content and saves in form of a stream
            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

            //using the uploadImage method of uploader class
            uploader.uploadImage(fileNameNew, fileContent);
        }

        try {
            response.sendRedirect("result.jsp");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            response.getWriter().append(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    } else {

        response.getWriter().append("Format is wrong");
    }

}

  // method for removing header for proper file upload
private String getFileName(Part part) {

    for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim()
                    .replace("\"", "");
            return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
                    .substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') +   1); // MSIE fix.
        }
    }
    return null;
}

 }
```

This is my FileUploader class

```
package upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * @author Iwan Cuche
 * @date:
 */

 public class FileUploader {

/**
 * This method reads a File
 * 
 * @param fileName
 * @param stream
 */
public void uploadImage(String fileName, InputStream stream)
        throws IOException {

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

        int data;

        while ((data = stream.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(data);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        System.out.println("Uploaded file successfully saved in "
                + file.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

}

 }
```

This is my Singleton class

```
package utils;

public class ServerCounter {

private static ServerCounter INSTANCE = new ServerCounter();

private ServerCounter() {};

public static ServerCounter getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

}
```

I hope someone can help me because I'm not sure how to go at it.

Comment: I imagine your main issue is going to be persisting the last used ID somewhere outside of the application, either in a database, or in a text file somewhere.

Comment: This will be a bottleneck. Can't you use some db sequence instead?

Comment: what do you mean by "every time i start the application"? do you mean every time i restart tomcat or every time i send request to server?

Comment: Well the problem is, that it is my first "bigger" project. So I need to go step by step. Right now I got this upload where the images are saved in a folder on my Computer. The next thing is this counter, and by "every time i start the application" I mean the start of the tomcat.

Comment: @Leo right now I don't use one, the next step would be the counter and then a DB usage(JavaDB)

Comment: ok, then you need to write the counter to file or database

Comment: Atomic long is ok for a single instance. Just be careful if you go clustered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, first you have to persist your counter if you want to get it after tomcat shutdown. we need listener for tomcat:

```
package utils;

public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce){ // we could call loadFromFile here as well
}

//will be executed at tomcat shutdown
void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce){
    ServerCounter .getInstance().writeToFile();
}

}
```

now the singleton(like in Marko's answer:)):

```
package utils;

public class ServerCounter {

private static ServerCounter INSTANCE = new ServerCounter();
private final AtomicLong counter;

private ServerCounter() {
     //load value from file, do you need help by it?
     long value = this.loadCounterFromFile();
     counter = new AtomicLong(value);
};

private long loadCounterFromFile(){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        //no problem if there is no file, we will return 0 in this case
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Test\\counter.txt"));

        String line = br.readLine();
        if(line != null && line.length() > 0)
             return Long.parseLong(line);
        return 0;

     //catch all exceptionse, because we could get NumberFormatException or FileNotFound from parseLong
     } catch (Exception e) {
         return 0;
     } finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}

public static ServerCounter getInstance() {
         return INSTANCE;
    }
public String nextval() { return String.valueOf(counter.incrementAndGet()); }



//will be executed by listener
public void writeToFile(){
    //write the counter to file
    writeToFile(counter.get());
}
private void writeToFile(long value){
    try{
            //you need folder c:\Test, file will be created automatically if there is no file, it will override the old file
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Test\\counter.txt"));
            //need "" to create String
    bw.write("" + value);
    bw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

now you can use ServerCounter.getInstance.nextval() to increment the counter and get the value

last thing is, you need to put the listener to your webApplication:

```
<web-app>
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>utils.ContextListener </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

EDIT: ServerCounter was implementing ServletContextListener by mistake

EDIT2: added read/write file

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, really appreciated. You even give me some code snippet. Have a nice day :) I will try to solve it from here now. Again thank you

Comment: The thing with the "load value from file" what would you suggest to do exactly?

Comment: simply create a new file and read it by FileReader. Do you need example of how to do this?

Comment: would be lovely to see one yes :)

Comment: i added file-Read/Write example. It will use c\Test\counter.txt file to store the counter.

Answer (score 3):

In ServerCounter, add

```
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

public String nextval() { return String.valueOf(counter.incrementAndGet()); }
```

Each time you call `INSTANCE.nextval()` you'll get a fresh numeric string.

Clearly, each time you restart your application, the counter will restart.

Comment: +1 Thanks, at least i got some idea how to actually handle it.